# Insert Date and time off by 6 days on trigger

Tags: sql-server

I have a trigger that executes fine and has been working well for 5 years. However today, a very odd problem occurred with the date/time of the trigger being off by 6 days to its preceding and following entries. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on what possible scenario could of caused this?

Trigger code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DateTriggerEventTimes]
ON [dbo].[EventTimes]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ES
        SET InsertDatetime = GETDATE(),
            LastUpdateDateTime = GETDATE()
        FROM EventTimes es
        JOIN Inserted I ON es.EVENTTIMESID = I.EVENTTIMESID
    END 

    IF UPDATE(LastUpdateDateTime) OR UPDATE(InsertDatetime)
        RETURN;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM INSERTED 
               -- make sure to compare inserted with (same) deleted personI
               JOIN DELETED D ON D.EVENTTIMESID = I.EVENTTIMESID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ES
        SET InsertDatetime = ISNULL(es.Insertdatetime, GETDATE()),
            LastUpdateDateTime = GETDATE()
        FROM EventTimes es
        JOIN Inserted I ON es.EVENTTIMESID = I.EVENTTIMESID
    END
END
```

The query in question has results that look like below with EventimesID 2760435 being the odd one out. All of these I have confirmed where entered into the database as roughly the same time by other means, which means this date is absolutely not supposed to be 6 days earlier than the rest.

| EVENTTIMESID | COMPLEXCODE | DELETED | LASTUPDATEDATETIME | INSERTDATETIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2760430 | 4 | 0 | 2021-02-15 14:13:34.070 | 2021-02-15 14:13:34.070 |
| 2760433 | 1 | 0 | 2021-02-15 14:14:25.100 | 2021-02-15 14:14:25.100 |
| 2760434 | 2 | 0 | 2021-02-15 14:14:48.623 | 2021-02-15 14:14:48.623 |
| 2760435 | 2 | 0 | 2021-02-09 13:11:22.610 | 2021-02-09 13:11:22.610 |
| 2760436 | 2 | 0 | 2021-02-15 14:15:24.380 | 2021-02-15 14:15:17.980 |
| 2760437 | 15 | 0 | 2021-02-15 14:15:26.580 | 2021-02-15 14:15:26.580 |

Comment: `UPDATE()` function always returns true for an insert. Maybe someone updated the column directly? And you are not joining on `inserted` and `deleted` so will update the whole table every time.

Comment: The most likely source is that someone changed the current datetime (or the timezone) of the machine on which your server instance is running - perhaps just temporarily.

Comment: And your trigger should not attempt to compensate for data errors. Your UPDATE block should not be setting the INSERTDATETIME **at all**. That simply covers up logic errors in  data entry. Rather, it would be good to throw an error in this situation to help you find and fix those problems.